# I just installed Python on my Windows 11 and it opened in a command prompt like a bad looking window. How do I change the interface?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just installed Python on Windows 11, and it opened via command prompt like a bad looking window. How do I change the interface?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "like a bad looking window?" That's the python repl. It's what running python looks like on all platforms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What do you want to change the interface to? Please [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Installing python only installs the python intrepreter to run programs from the terminal (what you've pictured). I'm guessing you want an "Integrated Development Environment". Try [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), it's one of the more popular options.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything weird in this window. Its the same across any OS version. If you feel it doesn't suit you, try out anaconda.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).